# Does the beta tag need clarification?

Tags: discussion

Right now the 'beta' tag refers to the distribution of that name. Does it need clarification or amendment to deal with `beta` as used in finance (a measure of risk, I think).

Answer (score 3):

It would do no harm to add a clarification inside the tag wiki, such as:

> Tag usage
>
> Do not use this tag for [Beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_(finance)) as measurement of how much an asset return can be predicted by a benchmark (finance context). Consider using the tags [finance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance), and/or [beta-risk](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-risk), instead.

This was just a rough suggestion (both wiki amendment and beta-risk tag).

It seems there are no current threads labelled [beta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta) outside the beta-distribution concept.
This is why I am suggesting to add the clarification inside the wiki and not inside the excerpt (but no objection using the excerpt, if one prefers).

Doing a research by [[finance] beta is:question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfinance%5D+beta+is%3Aquestion) it returned 4 questions. I believe the newest one is a candidate to place the new tag, if it is the case.

[Can I run a regression where dependents are coefficients from other regression and independents are R squared from these regressions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67198/can-i-run-a-regression-where-dependents-are-coefficients-from-other-regression-a)